# Linq not seeing properties

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have the following class and I'm trying to access it's properties from a different related class as follows:

```
var nuInfo = recipe.RECIPE_INGREDIENT
    .Select(i => i.INGREDIENT.INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO)
    .Where(ni => ni.NUTRITIONAL_INFO.Main == 1);
```

However, I can't access any (virtual or not) properties of `INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO`.

The `INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO` class is as follows:

```
 public class INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO
 {
     public int IngredientId { get; set; }
     public int Nutritional_InfoId { get; set; }
     public double Amount { get; set; }
     public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
     public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
     public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }
     public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

     public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers { get; set; }
     public virtual AspNetUsers AspNetUsers1 { get; set; }
     public virtual INGREDIENT INGREDIENT { get; set; }
     public virtual NUTRITIONAL_INFO NUTRITIONAL_INFO { get; set; }
}
```

Error Code is as follows:

> CS1061 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'NUTRITIONAL_INFO' and no extension method 'NUTRITIONAL_INFO' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing something in Linq? Am I trying to traverse across too many relationships?

Comment: can you access IngredientId? or you cant acces virtual entity types?

Comment: The key is the `ICollection` in your stacktrace. A collection of things is not the same as a single thing.

Comment: Could you show the related classes?

Comment: lazy loading enabled or disabled?@rory

Comment: @AlperTungaArslan lazy loading is enabled

Answer (score 4):

The error is because you're not adding `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` on the end of your query:

```
var nuInfo = recipe.RECIPE_INGREDIENT.Select(i => i.INGREDIENT.INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO)
.Where(ni => ni.NUTRITIONAL_INFO.Main == 1)
```

Your code is trying to access `NUTRITIONAL_INFO` as a property of the collection, not as the property of a member in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `nuInfo` is not just one `INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO` object, your LINQ query returns a result as a `IEnumerable<T>`.

If you want to get a single result you can use `First()`,`FirstOrDeafult`, `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault` to instead return a single result.

```
var nuInfo = recipe.RECIPE_INGREDIENT
.Select(i => i.INGREDIENT.INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO)
.FirstOrDefault(ni => ni.NUTRITIONAL_INFO.Main == 1);
```

Comment: I need to return a list of `INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO`

Comment: Your code looks like it should already do that, `recipe.RECIPE_INGREDIENT` is an`IEnumerable<INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO>` correct?

Comment: yes, `recipe.RECIPE_INGREDIENT` is an `ICollection<RECIPE_INGREDIENT>`

Comment: Then unless I'm mistaken `nuInfo` should be an `IEnumerable<INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO>` , is the linq statement where the error is comming from or is it somewhere else?

Comment: Having an `ICollection` and not `IEnumerable` led me to the answer which is: `var nuInfo = recipe.RECIPE_INGREDIENT.ToList().Select(i => i.INGREDIENT.INGREDIENT_NUTRITIONAL_INFO.ToList().Where(ni => ni.NUTRITIONAL_INFO.Main == 1));`